Defining relations.



Do these answers provide what is required?

Even(x)=∃k(x=2*k)
Triple(y,x)=∃x(y=3*x)


Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

I think that "you cannot use [...] the constant symbol $0$, or any other constant" tells you you're not allowed to use $2$ or $3$. Those two symbols should not appear in your solution.

You can try defining $0$ and $1$ and then $2$ as the least number greater than $1$.

$\exists n ( n \cdot n=n)$ holds for both 0 and 1 but $0<1$.
